# Python code for adding all even numbers and odd numbers separately and displaying into separate totals

Tags: python

I need to write a Python program that collects all the even numbers, adds them up and print the total into a variable X. Then it should collect all odd numbers, add them up and print them into variable Z.

range of numbers 1-20

I got introduced to Python yesterday and i have about no previous programming knowledge

I also tried with starting X at 0 and adding two in each step but it kept giving me syntax errors.

This is some of the code i did:

```
even_list = []
odd_list = []
li = range(1,21)
for i in range(len(li)):
    if i/2 == 0 :
        even_list.append(li[i])
    else :
        odd_list.append(li[i])
print even_list
print odd_list
```

Comment: You have to try code something.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: What do you mean by **all** the even numbers ?

Comment: Edit and show your code. Then we can help you.

Comment: I tried this: def is_odd(num):
    return num & 0x1

Comment: If you got introduced yesterday, I suggest that you start learning python by following virtually ANY tutorial... First you''l learn the basics, like variables, then lists, than using functions, and then defining functions. If at that point, you still can't work it out, return here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can get a list of numbers from 0 to 20

```
x = range(0,20)
```

This way you filter even numbers

```
even = filter(lambda x : x % 2 == 0, x)
```

This way you sum all the evens

```
x = reduce(lambda x, y : x + y, even, 0)
```

Do the proper thing for odd numbers ;-)

As you are new to Python, let me suggest you to read the [Built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) page in Python reference manual  to find some funny functions to do these kind of things.

Comment: Thanks.. I used your pointers and got the output : x - 90 y -100. Although the third statement is rather baffling. Because I used the variable "odd" for odd numbers and when i typed it exactly that way ( replacing the even with odd), I got the result.

Answer (score 1):

May be that helps:

```
>>>def func(n):
>>>  num = range(n)
>>>  odd = [x for x in num if x%2]
>>>  even = [x for x in num if not x%2 and x != 0]
>>>  return odd, even

>>> odd, even = func(20)
>>> print odd 
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
>>> print even 
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: WHat is the difference between "!=" and "<>"?

Comment: @user3222827 none in python 2.x, but in python 3.4  `!=` is the only accepted operator

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_even_odd_sum(N):
    sum_even, sum_odd = (0, 0)
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        if i%2:
            sum_odd += i
        else:
            sum_even += i
    return (sum_even, sum_odd)

(X, Z) = get_even_odd_sum(20)
print X
print Z
```

Tip: You might want to consider reading up on the basics of python like loops, ranges and functions before asking questions like this on SO.